# How can I force Visual Studio to allow editing code while running, while Edit and Continue is enabled?

Tags: visual-studio, edit-and-continue

I want 'Edit and Continue' to be enabled. I also want to edit code files will the game is running, with the understanding that those changes won't be applied immediately.

Basically Visual Studio is trying to protect me from confusion, as editing code while the game is running won't immediately apply to Edit and Continue. I would rather not have this protection. Any way to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way I've found to do this is to open a second instance of Visual Studio and open the code file in question, then you can edit it even if the executable is running. I would like to be able to do this with just one instance, though.